# How to write a fold-expr?

Tags: folding

I have read the help page about fold-expr ([`:h fold-expr`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/fold.txt.html#fold-expr)) but it didn't explain what's the syntax used in the expression.

There were there four examples:

1. `:set foldexpr=getline(v:lnum)[0]==\"\\t\"`
2. `:set foldexpr=MyFoldLevel(v:lnum)`
3. `:set foldexpr=getline(v:lnum)=~'^\\s*$'&&getline(v:lnum+1)=~'\\S'?'<1':1`
4. `:set foldexpr=getline(v:lnum-1)=~'^\\s*$'&&getline(v:lnum)=~'\\S'?'>1':1`

I understood that `v:lnum` is the line that needs an indention level, and that expression two is a call to a function.

what about expressions 1,3 and 4? Can someone please explain them to me?

Comment: My understanding is that the expression should return a number, and that number will be used to determine at which level the given line will be folded. 0 is not folded, 1 is the outermost fold, 2 is a fold nested inside a level 1 fold, and so on

Answer (score 17, accepted):

From [`:help 'foldexpr'`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27fde%27):

> It is evaluated for each line to obtain its fold level

The `foldexpr` is evaluated, so it needs to be VimL code; there is no mention of "special syntax" or the like. The result of this evaluation controls what Vim considers a fold or not.

Possible values are

```
  0                     the line is not in a fold
  1, 2, ..              the line is in a fold with this level
  "<1", "<2", ..        a fold with this level ends at this line
  ">1", ">2", ..        a fold with this level starts at this line
```

This is *not* the full list; just the ones used in the examples in your question. See `:help fold-expr` for the full list.

---

**First**

The first one is fairly simple once we add some spaces and remove the backslashes we need to get this working in a `:set` command:

```
getline(v:lnum)[0] == "\t"
```

1. `getline(v:lnum)` gets the entire line.
2. `[0]` gets the first character of that
3. and `== "\t"` checks if that is a tab character.
4. VimL doesn't have "true" or "false", it just uses "0" for false, and "1" for true. So if this line starts with a tab, it's folded at foldlevel 1. If it doesn't, it's not in a fold (0).

If you would expand this to *count* the number of tabs you would have indentation-based folding (at least, when `expandtab` isn't enabled).

---

**Third**

The third one is really not that much more complicated as the first one; as with the first example, we first want to make it more readable:

```
getline(v:lnum) =~ '^\s*$' && getline(v:lnum + 1) =~ '\S' ? '<1' : 1
```

1. We get the entire line with `getline(v:lnum)`
2. We match that as a regexp with `=~` to `'^\s*$'`; `^` anchors to the start, `\s` means any whitespace character, `*` means repeat the previous zero or more times, and `$` anchors to the end. So this regexp matches (returns true) for blank lines or lines with *only* whitespace.
3. `getline(v:lnum + 1)` gets the *next* line.
4. We match this to `\S`, which matches any non-whitespace character anywhere on this line.
5. If these 2 conditions are true, we evaluate to `<1`, otherwise, `1`. This is done with the "ternary"  `if` known from C and some other languages: `condition ? return_if_true : return_if_false`.
6. `<1` means a fold ends on this line, and `1` means foldlevel one.

So, If we *end* a fold if the line is blank and the next line is *not* blank. Otherwise, we're at foldlevel 1. Or, as `:h fold-expr` says it:

> This will make a fold out of paragraphs separated by blank lines

---

**Fourth**

The fourth behaves the same as the third one, but does it in a slightly different way. Expanded, it's:

```
getline(v:lnum - 1) =~ '^\s*$' && getline(v:lnum) =~ '\S' ? '>1' : 1
```

If the *previous* line is a blank line, and the *current* line is a non-blank line, we start a fold on this line (`>1`), if not, we're setting the foldlevel to 1.

---

**Afterword**

So the logic on all 3 examples is really quite simple. Most of the difficulty comes in the lack of spaces and some of the backslash usage.

I suspect that calling a function has some overhead, and since this is evaluated for every line you want to have a decent performance. I don't know how great the difference is on modern machines though, and would recommend that you use a function (as in the 2nd example) unless you have performance problems. Remember The Knuth: *"premature optimisation is the root of all evil"*.

This question [is also on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5977895/660921), which has a slightly different answer. But mine is of course better ;-)

Answer (score 3):

You're essentially asking what the other elements in these expressions are, which can be found by calling `:help` for any of them in turn:

```
v:lnum: the line being evaluated
getline(): get the line of text for a line number
==: equals
=~: matches
<cond>?<if-true>:<if-false>: evaluates to <if-true> if <cond> is true, else to <if-false>
```

I've broken down these expressions by their parts below to help illustrate their meaning:

1 Will return 1 for all lines starting with a tab and 0 for other lines:

```
v:lnum                      the current line number
getline(v:lnum)             the text of the current line
getline(v:lnum)[0]          the first character of the current line
getline(v:lnum)[0]==\"\\t\" the first char of the current line is 'tab'
```

3 Ends folds on blank lines after paragraphs:

```
 getline(v:lnum)=~'^\\s*$'                                       current line is only spaces
                              getline(v:lnum+1)=~'\\S'           next line has non-space
(getline(v:lnum)=~'^\\s*$' && getline(v:lnum+1)=~'\\S') ? '<1'   if both of these: <1
                                                              :1 otherwise: 1
(getline(v:lnum)=~'^\\s*$' && getline(v:lnum+1)=~'\\S') ? '<1':1
```

4 Starts folds on blank lines beginning paragraphs:

```
(getline(v:lnum-1)=~'^\\s*$'                                     previous line only spaces
                                getline(v:lnum)=~'\\S'           this line has non-space
(getline(v:lnum-1)=~'^\\s*$' && getline(v:lnum)=~'\\S') ? '>1'   if both of these: >1
                                                              :1 otherwise: 1
(getline(v:lnum-1)=~'^\\s*$' && getline(v:lnum)=~'\\S') ? '>1':1
```

The meanings of `<1`, `>1`, etc. are right below these expressions in `:help fold-expr`

Answer (score 1):

Accidentally posted my answer as a comment and submitted it early. Darn mobile.

My understanding is that the expression should return a number, and that number will be used to determine at which level the given line will be folded. 0 is not folded, 1 is the outermost fold, 2 is a fold nested inside a level 1 fold, and so on.

The expressions in the examples look like they'd evaluate to true or false. VimScript doesn't have a proper Boolean type, so this will really be 1 or 0, which are valid fold levels.

You could write your own expression using VimScript that is as simple as returning 1 or 0, or more complicated, allowing for nested folds.

Comment: Using just numbers will work, but it's worth noting that foldexpr's can evaluate to other special values, like =, a1, s1, >1, <1, -1